# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 using OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm getting this error, I've read other relevant post yet still can't find a solution.

When compiling, I am getting this error. I am using opencv framework and my own additional c++ classes.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Person::detectedPersonInImage(cv::CascadeClassifier, cv::Mat, double, int, int)"
```

Within the .mm implementation file I am using the c++ static method like so,

```
cv::Mat matImage = [image CVMat];
matImage = Person::detectedPersonInImage(cascade, matImage, scale, min_neighbors, max_size);
```

In the Person header,

```
static cv::Mat detectedPersonInImage(cv::CascadeClassifier cascade, cv::Mat image, double scale, int min_neighbors,
                                    int max_size);
```

In the Person.cpp file,

```
static cv::Mat detectedPersonInImage(cv::CascadeClassifier cascade, cv::Mat image, double scale, int min_neighbors,
                                    int max_size)
{
    //Work done here.
    return image;
}
```

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Regards, C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Person header, you should have something like this

```
class Person { // or struct Person
    static cv::Mat detectedPersonInImage(cv::CascadeClassifier cascade, cv::Mat image, double scale, int min_neighbors,
                                    int max_size);

// other things...
}
```

In the Person.cpp file, you should have something like this

```
// no static, add Person::
cv::Mat Person::detectedPersonInImage(cv::CascadeClassifier cascade, cv::Mat image, double scale, int min_neighbors,
                                    int max_size)
{
    //Work done here.
    return image;
}
```